# Render Dynamic Partial views on button click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking at different posts so that on button click can we do two actions.

My aspx page contains form and on button click it will submit form to controller and I am using form data in my controller and based up on the values in my form I am rendering partial views and I wan tto show my partial view in my aspx .

I am doing below steps :

```
   <form id="StatsForm" name="StatsForm" action="../Stats/Index/" method="POST"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
                <% Html.RenderPartial("OptionalFields"); %>
            </form>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                //<![CDATA[

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#GetReport").click(function () {
                        $("form[name=StatsForm]").submit();

                    });
                });

                //]]>
            </script>
```

My controller :

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        // Deal with the form 
        var strId= Convert.ToInt32(form["manufacturerId"]);
        var str1Id= Convert.ToInt32(form["reportId"]);
        var str2Id= Convert.ToInt32(form["categoryId"]);
        var str3Id= Convert.ToInt32(form["retailerId"]);
        var str4Id= Convert.ToInt32(form["countryId"]);
        var str5Id= Convert.ToInt32(form["regionId"]);
        var str6Id= (form["ManufacturerWidgetId"]);
        var startDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var endDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["StartDate"]))
        {

           startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["StartDate"]);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["EndDate"]))
        {
            endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["EndDate"]);
        }

        var reportName = _reportRepository.GetReport(reportId);


        var stats = new Stats
                        {

                            };

         switch (reportName.Code)
        {
            case "ABC":
                return RedirectToAction("InterStats",
                                    new
                                    {


                                    });
                break;
            case "XYZ":
                return RedirectToAction("ParametersCumLeads",
                                    new
                                    {

                                    });
                break;
            case "IMP":

                break;
        }
```

My partial view:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult InterStats(int str1Id, int str2Id, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var str = _manufacturerWidgetsRepository.GetManufacturerWidgetByManufacturerAndCountry(manufacturerId, countryId);
        var report = new ABCReport();
        var reportList = new List<ReportList>(); // a list of my anonymous type without the relationships
        report.reportList = new List<Record>();
        var count = 1;
        foreach (var mw in str)
        {
           // I am doing some function



            //  Create the data for the report
                       }
                return PartialView(report);
    }
```

And I am trying to display my partial view in my aspx.
  My question is without clicking my submit button twice how can I submit form to my controller and also inject my partial views in my aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

there are 2 things that you need to do to achieve this:

1. You need your controller to return a 'PartialView' (perhaps even a master `PartialView` that delegates out to the partials that you call in `InterStats`), rather than doing a `RedirectToAction`
2. Your `.submit()` action needs to be refactored to submit the form via `ajax` and then accept the returned `ActionResult` in the success callback and append that onto your page.

I'm in transit, otherwise would make a quick example. Will update later if still required.